# I am geting an error while building android project?

Tags: android

[image]

gen folder is missing is the issue.The build patch failed .I have tried all solutions posted previously on this and no luck.

EDIT

To make it clear here is my original post

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9460/encountering-issues-while-developing-android-hybrid-mobile-app

I am using salesforce SDK but when i am creating hello world app using native its working fine

Comment: You haven't given us much information but "Unable to Resolve target 'android-8'" looks like you need to download the SDK Platform (and any other packages you want) to use API 8... or change your manifest.

Comment: why the tiny picture? I love my 1080p monitor, but I really have to struggle to read anything there - at least link to a decent sized picture.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem to me. gen is a directory that Eclipse generates by itself, so if it hasn't permissions to create folders with the executing user, it might run into problems. What's your OS?

Comment: Apologies guys for making it unclear.Updated the link where i orginaly posted .

Comment: thanks @MohithKumar and all who contributed in this stach, i was stuck in same problem and was very helpful in resolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Hmm, everyone in *both* posts is telling you to download the "SDK Platform" for "Android 2.2 (API 8)". I *really, really* recommend trying this.  It is apparently required by the library you added to your project...

> I have 4.2 and 4.1 .Is that not enough?

No, you must have the older platforms that you are building against.

Simply download it and open `Project > Properties`, click on `Android`, then select `Android 2.2`. After all this clean your project and save it.

---

**Original Answer**
The screenshot doesn't give us much detail, but:

```
Unable to Resolve target 'android-8'
```

Tells me that you probably don't have the SDK Platform for API 8, simply download this through the SDK Manager. Or you can change any references in your manifest and the rest of your code to use an API that you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you delete the gen folder, it'll regenerate it after you compile your program.But if it is not then try creating a new project and try it again .If not , try a fresh installation of the API.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because when
you import a project, build
target is not set in the
project properties which
then default to the value
used in manifest file.  and make sure you have API 8.

The solution is to enable
build target toward your
installed API level (but keep
the minimum api support as
specified in the manifest
file).

Comment: Did you really notice this on your own or did you just copy my comment? Originally this only read "Clean it and rebuild"... By the way cleaning probably won't solve this error by itself.

Comment: @Sam i noticed that thing in second glance but any way i changed my answer...plz upvote it now..

Comment: Sure, now that you've put an effort into your answer I'll remove my downvote.